# How to disable ClickOnce message: "verifying application requirements"

Tags: clickonce

Users are complaining about an Outlook plug-in my developers created, saying that the "verifying application requirements" message appears when they open Outlook. We do want the check to take place, but users have requested that we hide it. Is this possible to do, and if so, what can I tell my developers to do? (What direction should I point them in?) Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dialog shows up when the application is checking for updates, and there's nothing you can do about it; it's inherent to ClickOnce deployment. It's also basically verifying against the server to make sure nothing has changed about your deployment (i.e. been tampered with).

You could stop using automatic updates and use manual updates instead, and write some programming to do that, but frankly, it's a lot of trouble just to keep what's basically a security/progress dialog from showing up. It would be easier to educate the users...

Comment: Thanks RobinDotNet. I figured as much but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything!